# Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found after Eclipse installation

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

Actually I installed hadoop successfully. hadoop version command worked fine. Now I wanted to run the map reduce program. So I installed eclipse. After which I am getting an error saying "Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found."

Even echo $JAVA_HOME command in cygwin terminal did not print the value after eclipse installation.

1. How can I fix this issue first?
2. How can I run the MaxTemperature map reduce program using eclipse.

Thanks

Comment: Which OS are you running your program: Windows, Linux, Mac?

Comment: Do you want to run map red on eclipse or test it on eclipse?

Comment: Windows 7 is the OS, I want to test it on eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Try to set JAVA_HOME. You can do this by editing your env.sh such that it will have:
`export JAVA_HOME=/absolute/path/to/your/java/home`

In case the path contains spaces, surround it with double quotes.

Example:

`export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/f/program files/java/jdk1.7.0_51"`

Comment: I have my env variable set correctly. I added  exec "$JAVA" -classpath "$(cygpath -pw "$CLASSPATH")" $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@" in  my bin\hadoop. With this, my set up worked really well. After which I installed eclipse plugin. This is where the problem is coming. JAVA_HOME is set in env variable but its not recognized in cygwin terminal now. Before Eclipse installation, JAVA_HOME was printed. hadoop version worked

Comment: How about trying to reset JAVA_HOME in cygwin again? Maybe for some reason, that environment variable got deleted.

Comment: Or maybe the problem may be in Eclipse not being able to detect the  Installed JRE. To configure this in Eclipse, go to Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. Select the default JRE. Then, click Edit > Add External JARs and select tools.jar file.

Comment: Regarding running a MapReduce program, there is a step-by-step guide here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/running-hadoop-mapreduce. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to refer to [Eclipse Runtime Options](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html).

- I would try first to launch Eclipse with the ***-clean*** option
- If that does not work, try launching Eclipse with ***-vm path to java vm***

There are things you can do to modify the *.ini* file directly, but if these two fails, try to reinstall Eclipse.  Remember, the ***java.exe*** exists in multiple locations on your PC. Changing your PATH variable manually might help you with Eclipse, but it may break other things.  This is why some products use *%JAVA_HOME%* to distinguish from the Java that might be loaded before it.

If you want to really know what is going on with your Java installation, open a command prompt window and type ***c:\> where java***.

[image]

As you can see, I have Java installed in multiple locations AND multiple versions of Java (7 and 8). It is important that you know these things before you start messing with environment variables.